# Subtracting mysql query results

Tags: mysql, difference

I am trying to subtract query results from two columns.

Table:

```
 id |   word1   | lang1 |   word2   | lang2 |
----+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+
  1 | car       |   1   | car       |  15   |
  2 | table     |   1   | table     |  15   |
  3 | Chair     |   1   | cahair    |  13   |
  4 | CDplayer  |  15   | CDplayer  |   1   |
  5 | car       |   1   | car       |  13   |
```

I would like to get all the words in word1 in language 1 that are not translated yet into language 12. So in this case it would be Chair

There are 3 million rows in the table and the following query takes 1 minute to run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word1 
FROM `translations` 
WHERE lang1 = 1 
  AND lang2 != 15 
  AND NOT IN (SELECT word1 FROM `translations` WHERE lang2 == 15) 
LIMIT 10
```

Doing a select on both rows separately is very fast 0.006s and then I could use `array_diff()` in PHP to subtract them from one another, but there probably is a simpler way to do it directly in MySQL.

Comment: imagine a dictionary where you have a word like car (word1) in English (lang1) that corresponds to wagen (word2) in German (lang2). I would like to know which words in English are not translated to German yet. Those English words might be translated to Spanish or Mongolian already but no to German. Those are the English words I would like to find. The ones not translated to German yet.

Comment: And why it would be `'Chair'` only and not all 5 words?

Comment: You might want to correct `WHERE lang2 == 15` into `WHERE lang2 = 15` first.

Comment: ypercube Because chair in language 1 is not translated into language number 15 but car for example is translated from language number 1 into 15. I only want the words in language 1 that have not been translated into language number 15.

Comment: inhan
That was already corrected adn the query works, it just takes toooooo looong to run

Comment: 12 is not equal to 15 !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    origin.word1
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT word1
      FROM tableX 
      WHERE lang1 = 1
    ) AS origin
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tableX AS trans
        WHERE trans.lang1 =  1
          AND trans.lang2 = 15
          AND trans.word1 = origin.word1
      ) ;
```

I would add an index on `(lang1, word1)` and an index on `(lang1, lang2, word1)` **before running these queries**.

You could also try this variation (and check both Explain plans):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      word1
FROM 
      tableX AS origin
WHERE 
      lang1 = 1
  AND 
      NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tableX AS trans
        WHERE trans.lang1 =  1
          AND trans.lang2 = 15
          AND trans.word1 = origin.word1
      ) ;
```

Comment: This gave me a Gateway Timeout:   The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

Comment: What gave you this? The query or adding the indexes?

Comment: the query, the indexes are on

Comment: wait, I only have separate indexes on the word1, word2, lang1, lang2, I need to put on the joint indexes. I will continue experimenting tomorrow as my host only allows 20 minutes of MySQL time a day.

Comment: @Sandor what continent is that?  Atlantis?

Comment: @Sandor It's just a very strange limitation (20 mins per day).

Answer (score 0):

This should have been simple

```
SELECT
    m.id ,
    l.*
FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                * 
            FROM mytable
            WHERE lang2 != 15
            GROUP BY id
) as l ON l.id = m.id
WHERE l.lang1 = 1
GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: This gives me an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm.id FROM mytable m INNER JOIN ( SELECT * ' at line 13

Comment: Slowest yet: Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 490,487 total, Query took 124.5793 sec)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NonTranslated.word1
from
(SELECT DISTINCT word1 FROM `translations` WHERE lang1 = 1 AND lang2 != 15)NonTranslated
left join
(SELECT DISTINCT word1 FROM `translations` WHERE lang1 = 1 AND lang2 = 15)Translated
on NonTranslated.word1 = Translated.word1
where Translated.word1 is NULL;
```

Let me know what is the EXPLAIN of this. I think it might be faster than select subquery.

PS : Assumption : Even if the word has been translated once, it is not to be included in the list.

Comment: this gives me an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'T1.word1' in 'on clause'

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Updated

Comment: id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 139566  Using temporary
1  PRIMARY  <derived3>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 32016  Using where; Not exists; Distinct
3  DERIVED  translations  ref  lang1,lang2  lang2  4   150362  Using where; Using temporary
2  DERIVED  translations  ref  lang1,lang2  lang1  4   523815  Using where; Using temporary

Comment: I got an error: The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

Comment: Try adding an index as suggested by ypercube before running the queries.
What is the timeout that you have set?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question totally correctly.  Does an aggregation work?

```
select word1
from translations t
group by word1
having max(lang1 = 1) = 1 and
       max(lang2 = 15) = 0
```